# Multidimensional array with different keys to format data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional dynamic array with following structure

```
$xData["invoice"]["no"]["data"] = "DY-13123";
$xData["invoice"]["date"]["data"] = "01-08-2018";
$xData["invoice"]["total_due"]["data"] = 56890.23;
$xData["invoice"]["due_date"]["data"] = "01-12-2018";
$xData["from"]["name"]["first"]["data"] = "Company Name, Inc";
$xData["from"]["address1"]["data"] = "12345 Sunny Road";
$xData["from"]["address2"]["data"] = "Sunnyville, CA 12345";
```

I want to allow users to format the data of array by specifying format. For example `$xData["invoice"]["date"]["data"]= "01-08-2018"` 
for this, user can specify the format as date type and formatting as "YYYY-mm-dd". I am storing this format information in another array.

```
$xFormat["invoice"]["date"] = array("date","YYYY-mm-dd");
$xFormat["invoice"]["total_due"] = array("currency","$");
```

Now, I need to get the value of $xData and apply the formatting. I have tried getting all keys and applying the format but no success. Please let me know how
to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Based on your provided code (if the rest follows the same patter) you don't need the `["data"]` part, you can omit it and just use `$xData["invoice"]["no"] = ...` instead.

Comment: $xData contains "Data" as well "labels" so we have used data as 3rd key.

Comment: I see, then it's justified with a 3:rd level

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, first take the string in `date` field and convert it to time, then format it with the format in `$xFormat`

```
$time = strtotime($xData["invoice"]["date"]["data"]); //converting the date in string to seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC
if ($time === false) { //if the date couldn't be converted to seconds
    echo "date is wrong";
} else {
    echo date($xFormat["invoice"]["date"]["date"],$time); //yes, double date fields is correct
}
```

The function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts a string representation of a time to seconds, which in turn can be used in [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Since you have set `$xFormat["invoice"]["date"]` as `array("date","YYYY-mm-dd")`, I had to use `$xFormat["invoice"]["date"]["date"]`

Comment: Problem is that it is complete dynamic and there can be many different formats for example, currency, number, date, string etc.

Comment: You can use only those accepted by PHP's date function for date (There are some libs that adds additional formats), and date accepts many different formats. Just check the php page for it. I believe this code **solves** your one problem and be an example to others on what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think it will fit for all possible options required.

Comment: It's not meant to be a fix for all, and cure for cancer etc. It's meant to be a fix for your problem and show you how to do it. We're here to **help**, not do it for you mate.

Comment: Thanks for help mate. I was not saying that you didn't help me, it just I can't use it until I got proper solution for all conditions, I am also trying at my end using some recursion. Let's see. Thanks anyway.